# Rails 3.1 - Trying to get check_box_tag to work with a lookup table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and I've been having fun, that is until my struggles with `check_box_tag`.  I've read a lot of the questions on this site and I still haven't solved my problem.  I'm convinced it is something I am just missing.

I have a `reportdetail` table and a `buginfo` table.  The `buginfo` table represents a readonly table of bugs I want to find in some program. The `reportdetail` table will hold reports that have will contain the list of bugs (from the buginfo table) that the user wants to find.  I can have many reports within the report detail table.

```
class Reportdetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buginfos
end

class Buginfo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reportdetail
end
```

Here is my schema.  It is simple:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20111221162309) do

  create_table "buginfos", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "reportdetails", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "buginfo_id"
    t.boolean  "bug_detected"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

And finally my partial _form.html.erb for `reportdetail`:

```
<%= form_for(@reportdetail) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <table>  
      <% Buginfo.find(:all).each do |buginfo| %>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= check_box_tag("[buginfo_id][]",1,buginfo.id) %> </td>
          <td> <%= buginfo.name %> </td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The form correctly shows a check box next to every bug and I can even click the check boxes, however the data is never saved.  I know the first parameter for `check_box_tag` needs to be unique and I'm pretty sure this is correct.  I know the second parameter is the value of the checkbox, but what does this really mean?  I'm assuming this means the current value of whether this bug has been selected or not, but since I haven't selected anything yet, I'm not sure what to do.  According to the docs I read the third parameter should be "Is the check box checked or not?"  But once again, what is this relative to? - the current value or ...

If the user is creating a new `reportdetail` and assuming there are 5 bugs in the buginfos database, I would assume 5 checkboxes to show up on the /reportdetail/new.  This happens correctly.  If I select 3 bugs for the reportdetail (selecting the checkboxes)  I would assume three records would be created in the database to represent each of the bugs the report wants to include.  This isn't happening at all. I just get one record and buginfo_id and bug_detected are both nil.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: What you really need is `fields_for` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Answer (score 1):

Your basic form_for / standard create action only really wants to create one object at a time.

As for the parameters to check_box tag,

- the first is the input name. This basically decides where in the params hash will this checkbox end up (if it is checked)
- the second is the value: if the checkbox is checked, what should be put in the params hash (if the checkbox isn't checked at the point of form submission, nothing is put in the params hash)
- the third is whether the checkbox should initially show as checked.

What I would do here is put

```
<%= check_box_tag 'buginfo_ids[]', buginfo.id %>
```

In the view, iterating over the bug infoseek as you are. The [] at the end of the input name means that rails will collect all the submitted values (ie the buginfo id ) for each check box into an array, so params[:buginfo_ids] will either be nil (no bugs selected) or an array of ids

Then, in your controller, iterate over that array  and create a reportdetail for each of these buginfo ids. It's not clear to me why you are creating multiple report details with one bug info each. If you wanted to have a single report detail that was habtm  buginfos you could skip the iteration bit in your controller and change the input name to reportdetail[buginfo_ids][] and rails should create the rows in the join table automatically.

Your schema also seems slightly add odds with your association declaration - if reportdetail has_many buginfos, then it doesn't need a buginfo_id. It feels like you actually want a habtm or has many through association.

Comment: After reading your comment I think I am starting to see what you mean.  I see why it is important to have the third table to manage the relationships between reportdetails and buginfos. I'll definitely look at the railscast episode 17 with regards to habtm.  I'll go through that example before I post anymore questions

Answer (score 0):

In view

```
<% Buginfo.find(:all).each do |buginfo| %>
<div>
  <%= check_box_tag 'buginfo_ids[]', buginfo.id -%>

  <%= buginfo.name %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

remember this in reportdetails_controller.rb

```
def update
  params[:buginfo_ids] ||= []
  #...
end
```

If you're new to rails check out railscasts. Ryan Bates has over the years made it an extencive libary. Search for "check_box"_tag and you'll get 10 minutes about it.
[#17 HABTM Checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes)

Comment: I'm now getting this error:  SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: buginfos.reportdetail_id: SELECT  1 FROM "buginfos"  WHERE "buginfos"."reportdetail_id" IS NULL AND "buginfos"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1  this actually makes sense to me because reportdetail hasn't been saved yet.   It's like I need to save reportdetail and then save the ids for the bugs.

Comment: Do i need to have the has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between buginfo and reportdetail?

Comment: I don't get the error but it doesn't work.  I think @Frederick Cheung has a good point about my associations between buginfo and reportdetail